# Commands in SwiftUI not fireing

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to receive Keyboard Commands.
Tried like this:

```
@main struct app: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
    .commands {
      CommandMenu("CustomCommands") {
        Button("command1",action:{print("command 1 executed")})
        .keyboardShortcut("x", modifiers: .command)
        Button("command2",action:{print("command 2 executed")})
        .keyboardShortcut("A")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Command Test")
      Button("command 3",action:{print("command 3 executed")})
      .keyboardShortcut("y", modifiers: .command)
      Button("command 4",action:{print("command 4 executed")})
      .keyboardShortcut("b")
    }
    
  }
}
```

The keyboard commands are not received on the iPad or on the Mac under Catalyst.
A menu entry does not appear on the Mac (Catalyst) as expected.

Xcode: Version 12.0 beta 2 (12A6163b).
MacOS: 11.0 Beta (20A4300b)

Comment: If this is supposed to work and doesn't, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I´m not sure, if I'm doing it correctly. Any hints here are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem was, I used "system shortcuts" like COMMAND-a and COMMAND-x.
Using COMMAND-1 and Command-2 it works fine now in BigSur Beta 3.

In [Use of "Command-a" as a Keyboard Shortcut for a Menue in SwiftUI 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088896/use-of-command-a-as-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-menue-in-swiftui-2-0) I asked, how to use "system shortcuts" like COMMAND-a.